# Style an entire road using Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing an app which given a postal code will return map of the area with all the roads in the 100m radius highlighted either green red or yellow based on our machine learning algorithm. My task is 2-folded

1. Gather all the roads in 100m radius given Postal code
2. Highlight those roads using different colours

Our solution to the very first problem is quite inefficient atm, we are trying to convert the postal code to LatLng and then calculate boundary boxes with LatLng +/- 100m and extract street names. This sadly uses so much bandwidth AND API calls that we must look for a new solution. Is there anything we could use instead?

As of highlighting those roads that are another problem, as I have encountered problems where the application needs to highlight specific route, which was solved using polylines based off points google maps API returned. In this case, though, no points are returned as of now.

I know that those are 2 question but they are so closely related to each other (as the output of 1st problem will be used in the drawing lines) that I've decided to ask them together.

Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case people are wondering how to solve similar question here's how we solved it:

Our current solution is sending the initial Postal Code and radius to OpenStreetMap API called overpass (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) which returns streets within given bounding box (which is calculated using postal code longitude and latitude) as a WAY (set of points in JSON format). The returned WAY can be easily visualised using polylines included in the google maps API.

Hope that helps!